# Value updates for all other items (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to code a shopping cart, where I change the amount of items and then I render the price. The problem is that when I increase amount of a single item, then every item gets its value increases. But I dont want that, I want to change the value only for the increased item.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import React from "react";

const ShoppingItem = ({count,setCount,name,price}) =>{
    const [innerCounter,setInnerCounter] = useState(0);

    const incrementHandler = () =>{
        setInnerCounter(innerCounter => innerCounter+1);
        setCount(count => count +1)
    }
    const decrementHandler = () =>{
        if(innerCounter>0){
            setInnerCounter(innerCounter => innerCounter-1);
            setCount(count => count -1)
        }
    }

    const totalPrice = () =>{
        if(count > 0)
        return price * count;
    }

    return(
        <div className="item">
            <button onClick={decrementHandler} className="btn inc space-around">-</button>
            <h2 className="space-around">{innerCounter}</h2>
            <button onClick={incrementHandler} className="btn inc space-around">+</button>
            <h1>{name} </h1>
            <h1 className="price"> {totalPrice()}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}


export default ShoppingItem;
```

Comment: if your setCount function is common for all items you will have to fix it by passing the id and setting the count for the item

Comment: can you please show me an example

Comment: Can you show me where and how you are using ShoppingItem ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Kapaak/pen/WNxpvYy?editors=1010 I have put all in the JS, First portion is ShoppingList.js and the second is App.js

Comment: You can simply show the total based on the innerCounter like  return innerCounter * count;

Comment: ye you are right, the innerCounter * count works. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome, still i would recommend you to move that to the outer component and managing it from there :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is whenever the setCount function is called, it increases the count value, which affects every item in the cart. Instead what you can do is call setCount function with an id, which could uniquely identify which cart item needs to be updated, hence solving the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Ye this makes sense mate. Unfortunatelly I am quite a react noob and it throws me error when I try to create key / id  (Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop). Guruparan Giritharan noted the solution for this, which helped me, but thanks for your REACTion (haha).